# How to read atrace data in compressed format

Tags: shell, adb, trace, systrace

I am using

```
atrace -z
```

to get compressed trace file. Is there any way to decompress this file to recover original data

Comment: Probably `gunzip` but `file atrace.out` will tell you about a great many file formats.

Comment: IIRC it's using zlib in the Python script. Take a look at the atrace script to see what it does.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's possible. There is just one "weird trick" to be done -- `atrace` prepends all of its output with `done\nTRACE:\n` string (see the [source](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/native/+/23c2fcbbf4be87580e64132150aa554b764425c2/cmds/atrace/atrace.cpp#876)), so these bytes need to be removed first, and then the rest is just an output from `zlib`'s deflate. See [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/22834/how-to-uncompress-zlib-data-in-unix) on how to decompress it.

For example (on Linux):

```
dd if=<compressed-trace-file> bs=1 skip=13 | zlib-flate -uncompress
```